# XML Schema Identity constraints - Can I use absolute path in XPath in selector?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, key, keyref

I want to implement referential integrity in a xml document using *key* & *keyref* in a XML Schema.

Let's say my XML looks like this:

```
<root>
  <parents>
     <parent parentID="P01">XXX</parent>
     <parent parentID="P02">XXX</parent>
  </parents>

  <sons>
     <son sonID="S01" parentID="P01">XXX</son>
     <son sonID="S02" parentID="P02">XXX</son>
     <son sonID="S03" parentID="P02">XXX</son>
  </sons>
</root>
```

In my XML, for example, I want to define the *parentID* attribute as a primary key for the *parent* element.

I declare the corresponding *xs:key* inside the *root* element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="root" type="myRootType" >
  <xs:key name="parentKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="./parents/parent" />
    <xs:field xpath="@parentID"/>
  </xs:key>  
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="myRootType">
   <xs:sequence>
   ....
```

It works fine (validation gives an error if two parents have the same ID) using a relative path ("./parents/parent) in the *xpath* attribute of the *xs:selector* element, as in the example shown above.

But the identity restriction doesn't work if I use the absolute path instead ("/root/parents/parent").

Why is this? my understanding whas that it should work in both ways (using abosolute or relative paths in the XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually XML Schema doesn't support *any* XPath expression in `<xs:selector>`, but a *subset* which doesn't include expressions that start with `/`. That is formally described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#c-selector-xpath).

Besides not working, your processor should have produced an error message since `/root/parents/parent` is an invalid expression.